# Is it normal to increase rent by 5% per year?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, real-estate-leasing

We are subleasing a part of commercial real estate (medical office in Brooklyn, NY), and now that 1 year is over, the landlord want to increase the rent by 5%. They claim that their landlord increases their rent by 5% **every year** and this is normal for commercial RE, "everybody does that".

This does not sound reasonable on the face of it (e.g., inflation is way below 5% ATM), but maybe there is something I don't know.

So, what do I do? Is it really true that cre rent goes up by 5% every year or are they bluffing? Should I expect the same 5% annual increase from all landlords?

Comment: Purely FWIW, i would say it is *not* the case that "everybody does that".  Such things are very local, though.   BTW I've always understood that in your scene, it's hugely advantageous to actually own your premises; of course, that can be a challenge.

Comment: One thing that every landlord does do, is negotiate the highest rate they can.  You make it look like you're ready to walk, and it may or may not still be +5%.

Comment: @user662852: I am afraid I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @sds It doesn't make any difference whether other people do it or not. If you're willing to pay 5% more each year, then your landlord is willing to take that. if you're not willing to pay 5% more each year, then your landlord will make a decision whether or not to accept less.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: it does make a difference! The question is: will _every_ landlord ask for 5% per year?

Comment: Not _every_ landlord does that. Anecdotal evidence - my landlord has not done that in years. Not sure if that helps with _your_ particular landlord, nor whether that answers the question.

Comment: The inflation rate really isn't the prime factor here.  What's important is the demand vs supply of that sort of office space in the Brooklyn.  That is, assuming you vacate, could the landlord rent the space for the new rent amount?  Could you find other suitable space at the old rate?

Comment: the reality is that you have to consider moving.

Answer (score 3):

I don't live in New York so I don't claim to know much about the New York real estate market. But 5% per year every year sounds ... very unlikely.

According to this source, http://www.millersamuel.com/files/2012/10/DE100yearsNYC.pdf, rents roughly doubled from 1980 to 2010, which comes to an average annual increase of about 2.4%. That seems like a plausible number to me.

The real thing is: can you get a better deal elsewhere? If your rent is presently 10% below average, a 5% increase is unpleasant but still leaves you with a good deal. If your rent is already above average and shows every sign of increasing rapidly, maybe it's time to shop for alternatives.

In any case, what else would you expect your landlord to say? I can't imagine the landlord saying, "Yes, we're jacking rates up way faster than all our competitors, and we know we can get away with it because our tenants are gullible idiots." Of course he's going to say this is normal. I'd shop around and see if he's telling you the truth or not.

Comment: LOL great final paragraph  :)